# Android: calling Java class from C++ Native Activity

Tags: java, c, android-ndk, native-activity

Java code:

```java
    package local.ttt;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;

    public class Text2Bitmap {
        static Bitmap getBitmap(String text,int fontsize) {
            Paint paint=new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setTextSize(fontsize);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

            int outwidth=(int)Math.round(paint.measureText(text));
            Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(outwidth,fontsize,Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);

            Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
            canvas.drawText(text,0,fontsize-1,paint);

            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

C source:

```
            ...
            MY_ASSERT(vm_cached!=NULL);
            JNIEnv* env;
            jint res=vm_cached->AttachCurrentThread(&env,NULL);
            MY_ASSERT(res==0);
            jclass activityClass=env->FindClass("android/app/NativeActivity");
            MY_ASSERT(activityClass!=NULL);
            jmethodID getClassLoader=env->GetMethodID(activityClass,"getClassLoader","()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;");
            MY_ASSERT(getClassLoader!=NULL);
            MY_ASSERT(nativeActivityObjHnd!=NULL);
            jobject cls=env->CallObjectMethod(nativeActivityObjHnd,getClassLoader);
            jclass classLoader=env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassLoader");
            MY_ASSERT(classLoader!=NULL);
            jmethodID findClass=env->GetMethodID(classLoader,"loadClass","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;");
            MY_ASSERT(findClass!=NULL);
            jstring strClassName=env->NewStringUTF("Llocal/ttt/Text2Bitmap;");
            jclass text2bitmapClass=(jclass)env->CallObjectMethod(cls,findClass,strClassName); //fails here
            MY_ASSERT(text2bitmapClass!=NULL);
            res=vm_cached->DetachCurrentThread();
            MY_ASSERT(res==0);
            ...
```

it fails with:

```
W/dalvikvm(5614): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'Llocal/ttt/Text2Bitmap;'
W/dalvikvm(5614): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4002d560)
E/AndroidRuntime(5614): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
E/AndroidRuntime(5614): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Llocal/ttt/Text2Bitmap; in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[.]
E/AndroidRuntime(5614):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(5614):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(5614):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(5614):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Any hint what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Code dumps aren't really kosher here

Comment: This question is a nightmare, but i took a stab at it anyway.  You need to identify which line of native code is causing the error (since we don't have line numbers).

Comment: i cannot use debugging in my anvironment. I testing on device I cant root. so debugging doesnt work here. the question is about c part, not java.

Comment: it causing error on "fails here" in c code.

Comment: See my answer then, try some of my suggestions.

Comment: My bad. it worked without changes, except i set android:hasCode to true in manifest. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with java class loader. Use this code:

```
MY_ASSERT(vm_cached!=NULL);

JNIEnv* env;
jint res = vm_cached->AttachCurrentThread(&env,NULL);
MY_ASSERT(res==0);

jclass t2bClass = env->FindClass("local/ttt/Text2Bitmap");
MY_ASSERT(t2bClass!=NULL);

jmethodID getBitmap = env->GetStaticMethodID(t2bClass, "getBitmap","(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
MY_ASSERT(getBitmap!=NULL);

jstring text = ...;
int fontsize = ...;
jobject bitmap = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(t2bClass, getBitmap, text, fontsize);
MY_ASSERT(bitmap!=NULL);

// process bitmap here
// ...

res=vm_cached->DetachCurrentThread();
MY_ASSERT(res==0);
```

Comment: thank you! the reason i "mess with class loader" is, according to i read in blog above and some other sources, when u using native activity, u must use class loader or "FindClass off of the JNIEnv will not give satisfaction. It won’t find your classes. The reasons are because the context of the JNIEnv FindClass has no awareness that your classes exist.". that's she said :). i tried your code, and it fails on MY_ASSERT(t2bClass!=NULL);

Comment: maybe i should add something to androidmanifest.xml? hmm. now its set for native activity and has android:hasCode="false".

Comment: Well if you don't have code, then of course JNI won't find your classes because they are not there :) Change hasCode to true. The JNI should work fine from NativeActivity and it can find and use your classes - there is really no need to mess with class loader. Here's another example how to use Java code from NativeActivity - comment #1 is mine, and it works fine in authors code: https://github.com/fabiensanglard/Shmup/tree/master/engine/android

Comment: just findclass without classloader should work, but doesnt work for me even with hascode=true.

Comment: also According to
https://github.com/fabiensanglard/Shmup/blob/master/engine/android/jni/android/android_main.c :  "* JNI ISSUE :
* New error now when trying to call Java method from my native code: NDK JNI ERROR: non-VM thread making JNI calls
* It seems the JNIEnv is not really valid when we receive it in the game thread. We need to attach the thread to the VM (AttachCurrentThread) and create a new JNIEnv
* http://android.wooyd.org/JNIExample/files/JNIExample.pdf
*
* SNAAAAP !! Even after attaching and getting a valid JNIEnv it seems we still don't have the right classLoader !!!!!!"

Comment: also found this(unconfirmed) : http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CYjGWY9ThUMJ:vkswtips.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-how-to-call-java-activity-using.html+&cd=1&hl=ja&ct=clnk&gl=jp

Comment: I guarantee you, there is no need to use class loader. I am myself calling Java functions form my NativeActivity without help of java class loader. Just get the jclass/jmethodid of needed method directly and call it.

Comment: For any one else who may run into this issue with the class loader not being able to locate any of your or third party classes, firstly make sure that hasCode=true in your manifest, and you need to make sure to set the classloader, if you dont set the class loader and simply just try using FindClass from your JNIEnv provided by the NativeActivity it wont work, simply put activity->env->FindClass uses the system classLoader and as such can not load anything but system classes, i hope this helps anyone else who has had issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is causing your error (you do not indicate where the lines are, or the particular line where you are having difficulty debugging), but I will go ahead and point out a few quick mistakes I see.

One first mistake is you need to use `CallStaticObjectMethod` since you are calling a static method.  Your `jmethodid findClass` has a methodID, not a class, which is misleading and wrong.  You also have two parameters, but you seem to be only passing one parameter.

Basically, you need:

`(env)->GetStaticMethodID(jclass,"method name", "Parameter list")`

--jclass is the class reference
--"method name" is the name of the method IN quotes
--"Parameter list" is the list of parameters, which you need to look up syntax.

Skipping a few things...To call your stuff you need:

`(env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(jclass,jmid,parameter1,parameter2)`

--jclass is once again the class that has the static method.
--jmid is the java method id which you get from the function above.
--parameter1 and parameter2 are the parameters required for the java method.

Lastly, I think this may just be preference, but I would not attach the thread to the JVM until you have all the necessary information to make the jump into the JVM.

Comment: thank you for answers! trying to use code from http://blog.tewdew.com/ "using jni from native activity"

Comment: the goal is just add simple java class to native activity eclipse project for making bitmap from text string. i want to use java class from c++.

Comment: Let me ease your pain some, Start at the beginning.  Read up on JNI, it took me quite some time to get JNI working in my implementation and making a C call into Java is not one of easiest parts to understand:
http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/index.html